# Should parcelable and parcel tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should [parcel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parcel) and [parcelable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parcelable) be merged? I can't really think of a question which would be reasonable to tag with one and not the other.

Comment: [parcel] is about the class, [parcelable] is about the interface

Comment: @paper1111 And how often do you want to discuss one of them and not involve the other? Or would it make sense for someone to watch/exclude only one of them?

Answer (score 0):

According to their own tags wiki, they both refer to Android API.

I didn't checked the questions in order to see if they have some which don't match Android API, however since the tag wiki is filled for both of them that would make just need to remove the tag from those questions.

So I'm in favour to :

- merge
- rename to a more meaningful name `android-parcel` as I don't think that parcel/parcelable are meaningful enough alone for Android API (I clicked on that tag expecting reference to logistic field where I discovered that it was Android in fact).

By the way, should I split that post to separate the merge and the rename ?